# Can we define a reminder email for the "start and wait for approval" action

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

We are migrating from Nintex workflows to Power Automate. And in Nintex, approvals are been created as Tasks, and for those tasks you can define Reminder emails to be sent as follow:-

[image]

so can we have this feature inside our "start and wait for approval" action inside power automate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is not natively part of the **Start and wait for an approval** action, but it can be implemented using parallel branches. The process to do so is described in this blog post: [Flow of the week: Approval reminders using parallel branches](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/approval-reminders-using-parallel-branches/).

[image]

Comment: that actully did the job.. thanks alot

Comment: @johnGu Glad to help